# how to Get CloudWatch Logs for last 30 minutes in command prompt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, command-prompt, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

how can I get last 30 minutes AWS CloudWatch logs  which are inserted  to the specific LogStream  using AWS Command ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe what you already tried yourself and what you ran into? Looking at the AWS CLI command reference, it seems that you should be able to run "aws cloudwatch get-log-events ----log-stream-name `<name of the stream>` --start-time `<timestamp>`" to get a list of events, starting at given UNIX timestamp, calculating the timestamp should be fairly trivial.

Addition, based on your comment: you'll need to look into the AWS concept of pagination. Most/many AWS API calls (which the CLI also makes for you) retrieve a size/length limited set of data and return a token if there is more data present. You can then make a subsequent call passing that token, which tells the service to return data starting at that token. Repeat this process until you no longer get a token back, at which point you know you have iterated the full dataset.

For this specific CLI command, there is a flag.

```
--next-token (string)

The token for the next set of items to return. (You received this token from a previous call.
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for your reply 
basically if i am using this command "aws cloudwatch get-log-events ----log-stream-name --start-time" then i am only able to retrieve around 1 MB data from the AWS Clouwatch logs and in one second in my logstream large amount of data getting logged.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies your question a lot. I've added additional explanation on the concept of Pagination, can you see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

use [log tail](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/tail.html)

aws logs tail --since 30m